# inference not working on type argument from a higher order function

Tags: typescript

I've slimmed this code down for this question.  Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDSxFwLxwM4xQCWAdgOZwA+cJArgLYBGwUV+iTEANgNwBQfUJFgJkqADIQAxgEMY0AGIkAPAFE4oGMBIATPHFVdg9bTAB8OOAApgRkyRgAuAwEocFgsXL9B4aPCkuGTx9SVl5KDUNEC1dfUNjUwsAbz44OCkIEk9aKQirMGIANzlUEhkTZ09SMjdkgF8BdLJgeB1gPCliMBgiLKsXKsIauFT09KhW2igSOAADABJkgCkAZQB5ADkAOmryIgAzRCsYAAsiPG3ykxd6uf50xsbfYQCgkLgASQcWGTzoKKabR6Ax2UwAGjgq2isRB3y0UD+EVWKCkhyI4T6KlUkNWZhSaQyWRy-ygVjgYFojC4GJoFWAQy8ZHBhPSlOptLwqPRmKyzlWLPGFKpNKkcC40jk0GcYSlkVUZkFcDqTwEQn8ohQXx+iNJ3wIMhIUmAgJiwPiYIcuJh5u1CKR0BRwDRBwxcixalx+Ms8N+pM9ULMPnVIiQWtlETwygFBhtcVBiQcFlwyTgAG0AApwUhwADWmAgByhAF0ZZKIko1BZ6sG-KGxHAI9BPvQwJaYO6sqbYRbEzBrUD477dcjua7edivcm4ITkmm0NnZvnEIWoWmAOQS8LQPDr4ul6wlLi0Bn4YbkNzYCzDh1QfUdo0mnGB54h+Bh1A30lOl1u3pd9RBxBBJ7H7KE4zhHVbx-HlO0nQNp1nVl8FsZ0IgAfkZGoHnGLc5TwZwACVnWgHRlGXVdVg3PDIz3SEmygSsFSDQkazVOt3wbL8IgAYWJQhcgibtbRAiFwKA-RuMdMc-w9Z88WTQkrCPE9MLPJlL2vKC9WyB9jQDPFa1eTVP20iIABUxGE+NRKtcSzSHMzpOdWD-3ghTLAYls2z7OCDJYl4NQOWgjTcjJJlKKT5Qg3tQLMKxrlPPZalGQlJhgaZZmjGK7T9UcXPHPz5PxKwuQK2S+VykdnN-Cd-M01KhUyXS4EmPBaC4Jw4BC3MSAgAB3WYU0aIV0sy1qOg6+Bgm6kheoG2YZqiyyUADD9VzK2q4JYx4+GeZqCEbUhc0sLpgEipzIgACXMgBZcRxGO2zzCsTdjvXFwrDGFCjFJZx1xkdclRondnG+9JGEQczzgI6xUNAhr4dMbZTkmA4lQhqHTjkZwbHbRH222XoYCMViWXqFwfAAeipkzs30Pr4FIA4WEmHQZz4R65u2SHobkV6DggCAPv4Lncx5rGLlexgZCgD6BD4A74E2yxvrwVC-rgAGgcJEGoFh8G4F5mHcaRhxnBu+6xeegm+xRtGMaNrGcbh9sLbuh6nvx9wNEJ4nScecmBBpuB+ugXN9H6ogzmiNsMWjkzFf4uAFFOiKtCi5RLc9ubnvit65o+5R1qLTb4s2lwBAUCW+ZgAWhZFvhq+NqX1xluXKaAA).

I have this function that returns a function with a type argument:

```js
export function createInteractor<E extends Element>(name: string) {
  return <S extends InteractorSpecification<E, S>>(specification: InteractorSpecification<E, S>) => {
    const result: unknown = {}
    return result as unknown as InteractorType<E, typeof specification>;
  }
}
```

The `InteractorSpecification` type looks for a property called locators that has fields that are dynamic and up to the user to add

```js
export type InteractorSpecification<E extends Element, S extends InteractorSpecification<E, S>> = 
  {
    selector?: string;
    locators: Record<keyof S['locators'], LocatorFn<E>>;
  };
```

The higher order function returns this type

```js
return result as unknown as InteractorType<E, typeof specification>;
```

`InteractorType` loooks like this:

```js
export type LocatorImplementation<E extends Element, S extends InteractorSpecification<E, S>> = 
  {[K in keyof S['locators']]: (value: string) => InteractorInstance<E, S>}

export type InteractorType<E extends Element, S extends InteractorSpecification<E, S>> = LocatorImplementation<E, S>;
```

Basically it takes the properties from the original `specification`'s `location` and maps them onto the return type.

The higher order function's type argument is not inferred but if I pass an explicit type argument in, it works:

```js
const Link = createInteractor<HTMLLinkElement>('link')({
  selector: 'a',
  locators: {
    byThis: (element) => element.href,
    byThat: (element) => element.title
  },
});

// type is not inferred 
// const Link: LocatorImplementation<HTMLLinkElement, InteractorSpecification<HTMLLinkElement, InteractorSpecification<HTMLLinkElement, unknown>>>
Link.byThat('foo');
Link.byThis('bar')


const spec = {
  selector: 'a',
  locators: {
    byThis: (element: HTMLLinkElement) => element.href,
    byThat: (element: HTMLLinkElement) => element.title
  },
  asfsdfsd: 'I also need to catch unknown props'
}

// works with explicit type
const F = createInteractor<HTMLLinkElement>('link')<typeof spec>(spec)

F.byThat('foo');
F.byThis('bar');
```

Answer (score 3):

The inference failures arise from `createInteractor` and are the result of improper use of generics.

```
function createInteractor<E extends Element>(name: string) {
  return <S extends InteractorSpecification<E, S>>(specification: InteractorSpecification<E, S>) => {
    const result: unknown = {}
    return result as unknown as InteractorType<E, typeof specification>;
  }
}
```

The inner function declares `S` correlating its type with that of `E` in the outer function. That is correct and desirable but the problem is that `S` isn't used in a context that it can be inferred from.

To fix that, we change the inner function to

```
<S extends InteractorSpecification<E, S>>(specification: S) => {...}
```

This enforces the same constraint, but associates `S` with the value `specification` such that S is inferred from the argument passed for `specification` at the call site and, critically, `S` in its constraint `extends InteractorSpecification<E, S>` is infererred from that argument as well, ultimately determining the `locator` and locator types.

While this one change is enough to fix the specific problem you are having, there is a related problem again arising from generics in `createInteractor`, but this time in the type parameter `E`.

Whenever you have a type parameter that isn't involved in the type of any of a function's arguments, you should do a double take. It is often a type assertion masquerading as a type parameter.

In our specific case, it allows us to write code like

```
const F = createInteractor<HTMLLinkElement>('input')(spec)
```

Even though spec is supposed to be for `HtmlLinkElement`s.

TypeScript's built-in DOM types, in `lib.dom.d.ts`, provide a useful type called `HtmlElementTagNameMap` which maps tag names to the their corresponding element types (this is how `document.querySelector('input')?.value` typechecks).

We will use this information to prevent prevent such invalid calls, and further improve the consumption experience at the same time, by taking a specific tag name and using it to determine and propagate the element type.

```
function createInteractor<N extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(name: N) {
  type Tag = HTMLElementTagNameMap[N];
  return <S extends InteractorSpecification<Tag, S>>(specification: S) => {
    return {} as InteractorType<Tag, S>;
  }
}
```

And thus we may now write

```
const Link = createInteractor('link')({
  selector: 'a',
  locators: {
    byThis: (element) => element.href,
    byThat: (element) => element.title
  },
});

// type is inferred 

Link.byThat('foo');
Link.byThis('bar')
```

safely and concisely while we desirably now receive an error for

```
const badSpec = {
  selector: 'a',
  locators: {
    byThis: (element: HTMLInputElement) => element.value, 
    byThat: (element: HTMLLinkElement) => element.title
  },
}
// error is correctly given for incompatible locator 
const bad = createInteractor('link')(badSpec);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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-HNv+rJrlAs6ejWsoLgIdbwJhGYVhEADC8qELkET7umpHHuRxH6Nhl65rRBH0VKjFATIIHAFx+DauQUEwVREbZIhsZVlKi6EsGWG+REzRiCZnZmSeCZnhF2ZXvhRYoY5lgKRuW5HnRQUqehIh1LQMb2Rk7ylNZNJ9BR+iSQsHTbisAwmOsZhWOiYFwH02yylpKyWA1ZnNWsIyTH0Gy8e8MCfN8ra1dpF7JbZ155Ssd5WHgKU3pa3lwMxbwfF8+27HAwRwCVVQkBAADu3znVVUBRSgyjrdWvF4gImT+aupBVJYFzAJVSVKl+f0fi4VjMaxRiKs4H4yB+3oyb+zgHXAjCIM0yKCdYbFdHt+OmBCiLvHU3rpJj2NyM4NjboT24QtcMBGKpuq7C4PgAPRc2Fw76KQdQsO8OhwAI4h-RCVOInIVgfnUEAQBD-ASyQVRS1jONy4wMhQBDAh8N9BAmrmljQ2xcNwAjSOyijUC4+j0sorTRMOM4DWq1UZkM0eJNkxTGOazTePbu7bTiJ73vuBojPM6zuLswIPN8yiz5C1AIti0b8AKADFVaI9ctqmrEObYKLhfQZGMyDouFm7KMPsS6VuI8j06o-teqB9jzsh0eYftOSBowFH0Ex77wGgQH0vB3T-fzOHkf09HrswEzRAs8AbP+nwyfC9A-Nyhn7FcFgZBEEU2hwArrCkJkm6FqqqB21nVc66LuCA8DmaKkX4OQ+-XCnMBAKA1tTGAcsFZK2AaAp2eBta62VkAA)

Comment: thank you for your answer.  The `name` argument of `createInteractor` is actually nothing to do with the element type.

In the real code, it is just used for debugging so it could be anything.

The original code actually is `<S extends InteractorSpecification<Tag, S>>(specification: S)`

But that means any key can be passed to so:

```
const Link = createInteractor<HTMLLinkElement>('link')({
  selector: 'a',
  locators: {
    byThis: (element) => element.href,
  },
  sdfds: 'aaa'
});
```
Is valid with the property `sdfds` that is why I changed it to a concrete type.

Comment: I see, sorry about that. However, I would recommend that you introduce a second argument for the tag name, or make the tag name a property of the `specification` type so that you don't have to pass explicit generics.